# Restore kernel from live usb

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, uefi

while installing another distro (Arch) I accidentally formatted my efi system partition. 
I then grabbed the chance and switched to systemd-boot.
Arch boots fine now, but I want to add Ubuntu again and dual boot. Ubuntus root partition should be fine but since I wiped the efi system partition I guess I have to reinstall the kernel.

I tried chrooting from a live usb and install the kernel via apt-get but it says the kernel is on newest version.

```
sudo su
mount /dev/sdb5 /mnt      # ubuntu root
mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/boot # esp
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
chroot /mnt
```

Then trying to install the kernel:

```
apt-get install linux-image-generic
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux-image-generic is already the newest version (4.13.0.38.41).
0 upgaded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded.
```

Am I wrong, is the Kernel still there? How can I add Ubuntu to systemd-boot if the efi program is not on the esp?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The kernel is installed to your filesytem partition, not the efi partition. The efi partition contains the grub bootloader files which are loaded before the OS would boot.

 To add Ubuntu to the grub boot-manager first boot into Arch (since your arch installation can boot fine) and ensure the ubuntu linux partition is mounted. After that do a simple

```
# update-grub
```

OR

```
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

This would  scan and find the kernels of each OS and add it to 
the grub boot menu. So anytime you turn on the pc you just pick which OS to run